# Uso de acumuladores en elemento de matriz y contador de iteraciones en Do..While

Tags: javascript, array, bucles

*Hola , estoy aprendiendo Javascript y me he encontrado con esto:*

```
 var depositos=[];
  var nro,monto;
  do {
    nro=prompt('Ingrese nro de cliente','');

    nro=parseInt(nro)
    if (nro!=0)
    {
      monto=prompt('Ingrese monto a depositar','');

      monto=parseInt(monto);

      depositos[nro]=monto;
    }
  } while (nro!=0);
  var suma=0;
  var canti=0;
  for(var f=0;f<depositos.length;f++)
  {
    if (depositos[f]!==undefined)
    {
      suma=suma+depositos[f];
      canti++;
    }
  }
  document.write('Cantidad de depósitos:'+canti+'<br>');
  document.write('Total depositado por todos los clientes:'+suma);
```

*Básicamente lo que hace es solicitar un valor de cliente que se usará como el 
indice del array y un monto a depositar que será el valor de ese indice, para mostrarlos con document.write el total de depósitos y el total de los montos depositados, el programa finaliza ingresando un 0 en el número de cliente.
Mi problema es que no sé como hacer lo siguiente:*

**1) Que si al ingresar por segunda vez el mismo número de cliente osea el mismo indice del array , envés de reemplazarse el antiguo valor del indice del array por el nuevo, se sumen el antiguo valor con el nuevo valor, porque si por segunda vez ingreso el mismo nro de cliente (indice del array) , e ingreso un nuevo valor diferente al anterior , este valor de indice se reemplaza por el nuevo , que debo hacer?**

**2) Lo mismo con la cantidad de depósitos, me sucede que si en la primera y segunda vez coloco el mismo indice (número de cliente) , me cuenta solo 1 depósito independientemente que los valores sean diferentes.**

Comment: Por definición en un "array denso" los elementos se deberían crear de forma continua y no haber lagunas, pero en el código publicado no importa si se cumple con esto o no. ¿Por qué poner "array denso" en el título? Dejando esto de lado el título es demasiado genérico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. En `depositos[nro] = monto;` cambiar el `=` por `+=`, pero primero debemos asegurar que el elemento existe.
2. Al poner `canti++;` en el `for` que recorre los elementos del array, estas contando los elementos. Para contar los depósitos, debe incluirse este en el `do`.

```js
var depositos=[];
var nro,monto,canti=0;

do {
  nro=prompt('Ingrese nro de cliente (0 para salir)','');

  nro=parseInt(nro)
  if (nro!=0)
  {
    monto=prompt('Ingrese monto a depositar','');

    monto=parseInt(monto);
    // Línea nueva. Si elemento de la matriz no existe, inicializarlo con 0
    (depositos[nro] == undefined) ? depositos[nro] = 0: false;
    // Línea modificada. Cambiar = por +=
    depositos[nro] += monto;
    // Contador de depósitos
    canti++
  }
} while (nro!=0);

var suma=0;
//var canti=0;

for(var f=0;f<depositos.length;f++)
{
  if (depositos[f]!==undefined)
  {
    suma=suma+depositos[f];
    //canti++;
  }
}
document.write('Cantidad de depósitos:'+canti+'<br>');
document.write('Total depositado por todos los clientes:'+suma);
```

Comment: yay! muchas gracias , actualmente soy muy teórico me falta muchísima practica

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tenes acá es mas que todo el algoritmo.

Primero, a que queres llegar? que resultados estas buscando.

Fijate que el punto 1, se soluciona cambiando

```
depositos[nro]=monto;
```

por

```
depositos[nro]=depositos[nro]+monto;
```

y el segundo punto, es un problema, porque con tu estructura de datos actual, en realidad no sabes cuantos depósitos reales existen. Lo que podes hacer es contara la cantidad de depósitos ingresados por el usuario al principio, cada vez que hace un ingreso.

Igual estoy suponiendo que esto es mas un ejercicio teórico que real, porque nunca usaría como indice de un vector el numero de cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre esto, guardar en un array asociativo el numero del cliente y el monto, así sin importar que el cliente sea el mismo no importa se guarda y puedes obtener el monto, inclusive podrías saber cuantas veces depositó el cliente x.

[Ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/dq7Luz18/)

```
    var depositos=[];
  var nro,monto;
  do {
    nro=prompt('Ingrese nro de cliente','');

    nro=parseInt(nro)
    if (nro!=0)
    {
      monto=prompt('Ingrese monto a depositar','');

      monto=parseInt(monto);

      depositos.push({
        cliente: nro,
        monto : monto
      });
    }
  } while (nro!=0);
  var suma=0;
  var canti=0;
  for(var f=0;f<depositos.length;f++)
  {
    if (depositos[f]!==undefined)
    {
      suma=suma+depositos[f].monto;
      canti++;
    }
  }
  document.write('Cantidad de depósitos:'+canti+'<br>');
  document.write('Total depositado por todos los clientes:'+suma);
```